# Python pandas groupby difference with other row filtered by column

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling with Python Pandas with groupby. How should I accomplish the following? For every fruit I would like to find the difference with the 'step 0' value of that fruit.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit' : ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Banana'], 'Step' : [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], 'Value' : [100, 102, 105, 200, 210, 195] })

    Fruit  Step  Value     to-be
0   Apple     0    100  -->  0
1   Apple     1    102  -->  2
2   Apple     2    105  -->  5
3  Banana     0    200  -->  0
4  Banana     1    210  --> 10
5  Banana     2    195  --> -5
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df.groupby('Fruit').apply(lambda g: g.Value - g[g.Step == 0].Value.values[0])
```

First, we're grouping by the column you care about (Fruit).  Then we're applying a function to each group (using a `lambda` which lets us specify a function in-line).  For each group, we find the row(s) where `g.Step == 0`, then get the Value entry from that row, and use `values[0]` to get the first Value (in case there were multiple places where `g.Step == 0`).  Then we just subtract that one value from all the rows in the group, and return it.

If you want to add it as a column to the dataframe, you can drop the index:

```
res = df.groupby('Fruit').apply(lambda g: g.Value - g[g.Step == 0].Value.values[0])
df['Result'] = res.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This line `df['Result'] = res.reset_index(drop=True)` doesn't work for me for `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, indices imply 3`

Comment: @sparkandshine that's odd.  What version of python are you using?  This runs fine for me on 2.7.3.

Comment: My Python version is  `2.7.6`.

Comment: I paste the traceback on my anser.

Comment: @sparkandshine updating now, will see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Think this does the trick. It simply loops through the rows and applies a new 'first' value each time the step is equal to 0. Then calculates the difference from that first value.

```
rows = range(df.shape[0])
df['count'] = 0
for r in rows:
    step = df.iloc[r,1]
    value = df.iloc[r,2]
    if step == 0:
        first = value
    df.iloc[r,3] = value - first
```

Comment: This definitely works, but on larger dataframes it's going to be slower than grouping.  In general, iterating through individual rows doesn't take full advantage of what pandas has to offer.  (I mention this not to attack your answer, but because someone gave me the same tip when I started learning pandas and it was really helpful).

Comment: I completely agree, your answer is definitely stronger here. I do however sometimes think (especially since this seems to be for beginners) something simple can be worked on and added to more easily. I found 'lambda' difficult to get my head around when I started!

Comment: Very true!  And it's always useful to see that there are multiple ways of doing things (and I'm pretty sure there's a better method than the one I put in).

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie to pandas, but at least the following code works. The end of result,

```
    Fruit  Step  Value  to-be
0   Apple     0    100      0
1   Apple     1    102      2
2   Apple     2    105      5
3  Banana     0    200      0
4  Banana     1    210     10
5  Banana     2    195     -5

[6 rows x 4 columns]
```

---

The source code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit' : ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Banana'], 
                    'Step' : [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], 
                    'Value' : [100, 102, 105, 200, 210, 195] })

list_groups = list()

# loop over dataframe groupby `Fruit`
for name, group in df.groupby('Fruit'):
    group.sort('Step', ascending=True) # sorted by `Step`

    row_iterator = group.iterrows()

    # get the base value
    idx, first_row = row_iterator.next()
    base_value = first_row['Value']

    to_be = [0] # store the values of the column `to-be`
    for idx, row in row_iterator:
        to_be.append(row['Value'] - base_value)

    # add a column to group
    group['to-be'] = pd.Series(to_be, index=group.index)

    list_groups.append(group)


# Concatenate dataframes
result = pd.concat(list_groups)

print(result)
```

---

@ASGM, I run your code,

```
res = df.groupby('Fruit').apply(lambda g: g.Value - g[g.Step == 0].Value.values[0])
df['Result'] = res.reset_index(drop=True)
```

but encounter the issue,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***.py", line 9, in <module>
    df['Result'] = res.reset_index(drop=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1887, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1968, in _set_item
    NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1068, in _set_item
    self._data.set(key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3024, in set
    self.insert(len(self.items), item, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3039, in insert
    self._add_new_block(item, value, loc=loc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3162, in _add_new_block
    self.items, fastpath=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1993, in make_block
    placement=placement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 64, in __init__
    '%d' % (len(items), len(values)))
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, indices imply 3
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```